# regex match not working for any input

Tags: java

I worked out in the tester that my regex should work for the lines I want to find, but when I use the input from the text file, I don't get a match even if my `searchString` is `.*the.*`  Any advice will be appreciated.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("ValenciaCourses.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String myRegex = null;
int count = 0;

br.mark(2000);
while(br.readLine() != null) {
    br.reset();

    try {
        myRegex = br.readLine();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myRegex);
        String searchString = ".*[3-6](\\s*)";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchString);
        boolean found = false;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            count++;
        }
    }catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
        System.out.println(myRegex);

    }finally {


    }

    br.mark(2000);
```

Comment: It looks to me like `myRegex` and `searchString` need to be swapped. You're searching for matches in the regex instead of searching for matches from the regex.

Answer (score 0):

it look like you are compiling the lines that you are read from the file not compiling the regex

you have to compile your regex not the line from the file

this might help you

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("ValenciaCourses.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String myRegex = ".*[3-6](\\s*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myRegex);

String currentLine=null;
int count = 0;

br.mark(2000);
while((currentLine=br.readLine()) != null) {

try {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(currentLine);
    boolean found = false;
    if (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }
}catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
    System.out.println(myRegex);
}
```